# Function to multiply element of list to number next to it

Tags: python, list, multiplication

Im writing a function that multiplies the element in the list with the number next to it, and the last number by itself. This is the code

```
def multiplyNums(aList):
     newList=[]
     for x in range(len(aList)):
          if x < len(aList):
               newList.append(aList[x]*aList[x+1])
          else:
               newList.append(aList[x]*aList[x])
     return (newList)
```

I really thought this would work, but theres something wrong with the range? In line 5.

Comment: Could you expand on *"something wrong"*? Provide a [mcve].

Comment: Simply setting the condition to `if x < len(aList)-1` should fix this.

Answer (score -1):

You going one index too far. Note that the last element in a list has index `len(aList)-1`.

Change this:

```
if x < len(aList):
```

with:

```
if x < len(aList)-1:
```

Answer (score -1):

Another aproach using itertools, `zip` the list with himself but the first element, `map` the result with the `mul` operator, transform it to a list and concatenate the multiply of the last element with himself:

```
import operator
import itertools
def multiplyNums(aList):
    return list(itertools.starmap(operator.mul, itertools.izip(aList, aList[1:]))) + [aList[-1]*aList[-1]]
print(multiplyNums([1,2,3,4,5,6]))
[2, 6, 12, 20, 30, 36]
```